# Create calculated field in Visual Basic

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, calculated-field

I would like to create a calculated field within one of my tables within the database. I am using `visual basic` and my IDE is visual studio.

I recently created the same database using access and used the following calculation within a calculated field’s expression:

```
 (([Grade1]/10)*2)+(([Grade2]/10)*3)+(([Grade3]/10)*5)
```

As a first go I just pasted to code into the default value or binding of the field as a long shot, but got an error. Guess I’m not allowed to make calculations using data from existing columns.

[image]

Can anyone help me with creating this field? The field does not need to be within the database it would be preferred however if it could be calculated outside of the database on a form using `datagridview` or something like that would be fine.

Grade 1, 2 and 3 contain's a number from 0 to 100.

I can’t find any tutorials unless anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the calculated field as described you should use the following T-SQL code:

```
create table dbo.Enrolement
    (
     StudentID int not null,
     ModuleNUmber int not null,
     Grade1 nchar(3) not null,
     Grade2 nchar(3) not null,
     Grade3 nchar(3) not null,
     Overall as cast(((Grade1 / 10 * 2) + (Grade2 / 10 * 3) + (Grade3 / 10 * 5)) as nchar(10))
    )
```

Yet, I do not understand why you are storing the grades as text. More over, your T-SQL code **requires** an implicit conversions of the text to numbers, make the calculation, and then revert it back to text again. Furthermore, during the conversion you are not telling SQL what do convert to. So, if you have grades with decimal places then a `SELECT` from the table will fail.

```
insert into dbo.Enrolement
        (
         StudentID,
         ModuleNUmber,
         Grade1,
         Grade2,
         Grade3
        )
values  (
         2, -- StudentID - int
         101, -- ModuleNUmber - int
         N'1.2', -- Grade1 - nchar(3)
         N'1.8', -- Grade2 - nchar(3)
         N'3.9'  -- Grade3 - nchar(3)
        )
select *
from dbo.Enrolement
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Conversion failed when converting
>   the nvarchar value '1.2' to data type int.

So, I'd very much recommend you using numbers to store your grades if they are to be used in a calculation afterwards. Here is the same table with numbers instead:

```
create table dbo.Enrolement
    (
     StudentID int not null,
     ModuleNUmber int not null,
     Grade1 decimal(9, 3) not null,
     Grade2 decimal(9, 3) not null,
     Grade3 decimal(9, 3) not null,
     Overall as ((Grade1 / 10 * 2) + (Grade2 / 10 * 3) + (Grade3 / 10 * 5))
    )
```

I have chosen to use `decimal(9,3)` because any precision from 1 to 9 uses the same amount of storage in bytes. At the same time I limited the decimal places to three and thus allow for rounding on two decimal places. At the same time there is ample of room to potentially "add" grades (if this should ever make sense) to a grand total of 999999.999

Comment: Thank you good sir, I got a little confused with that so I used nchar as it can store numeric values (as well as text obviously). What would be the best data type to use, Numeric? The data type says numeric(18,0) what does the 18 and zero stand for? Obviously they can be changed but does it have anything to do with highest and lowest value that can be entered?

Comment: I'd recommend using `decimal(9,3)`. This will store numbers with three decimal places and 6 (9 less 3) places before the comma. Hence the highest stored value for any given grade can be `999999.999`. For more information have a look at the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx